# Adaptar consultar para criar VIEW que devolve soma da contagem de duas Subqueries

Tags: mysql, refatoração

De [acordo com a documentação](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/view-restrictions.html), o MySQL não permite o uso de *subqueries* no `FROM` quando a consulta é uma `view`:

> Subqueries cannot be used in the FROM clause of a view.

Que resulta no seguinte erro:

> 1349: View's SELECT contains a subquery in the FROM clause

A seguinte consulta devolve a soma da contagem dos registos de cada tabela:

```
SELECT SUM(total)
FROM (
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS total
    FROM tabela1
    WHERE escondido='não'

    UNION ALL

    SELECT COUNT(*) AS total
    FROM tabela2
    WHERE escondido='não'
) t
```

Assumindo 1000 registos na `tabela1` e 500 na `tabela2`, a consulta devolve 1500.

---

Com a seguinte alteração à consulta, já é possível criar a `view`, mas o resultado são duas linhas, cada uma com o total de registos de cada tabela:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS total
FROM tabela1
WHERE escondido='não'

UNION ALL

SELECT COUNT(*) AS total
FROM tabela2
WHERE escondido='não'
```

#### Como manter o conceito original da consulta utilizando a mesma numa `view` ?

Comment: `SELECT Sum(total) FROM View_no_Mysql_que_nao_aceita_subquery` não soluciona seu problema?

Comment: @gmsantos De certa forma deverá resultar, mas a ideia é que a `view` em si devolva o resultado do `SUM()` e não valores para serem processados.

Comment: Sem subquery acho complicado... vou tentar aqui com `outer join`. Por essas e outras estou largando o MySql

Comment: @gmsantos Obrigado pelo apoio, coloquei agora uma resposta com uma solução que vai ao encontro do que procurava... Tenho estado a testar o assunto e desta forma consigo resolver a questão.

Answer (score 5):

Após alguns testes, eis uma forma de resolver a questão:

```
SELECT (
    (SELECT COUNT(*) AS total
     FROM tabela1
     WHERE escondido='não')

    +

    (SELECT COUNT(*) AS total
     FROM tabela2
     WHERE escondido='não')
) AS total
```

Básicamente passei a lógica aplicada no `FROM` para o `SELECT` indo ainda ao encontro do pretendido dentro das regras do MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

Outras duas alternativas seriam:

- Utilizar um `Sum()` fora da view:

  ```
  SELECT Sum(total) FROM View_no_Mysql_que_nao_aceita_subquery
  ```
- Criar uma `view` para a `view`

  ```
  CREATE VIEW mysql_precisa_de_gambiarras AS
  SELECT Sum(total) FROM View_no_Mysql_que_nao_aceita_subquery
  ```

  Por fim ficaria:

  ```
  SELECT * FROM mysql_precisa_de_gambiarras
  ```

Comment: +1 pelo nome das views :)

Answer (score 0):

Você pode executar o seguinte comando SQL:

[image: Comando SQL]
Ou então você pode adicionar 1 campo na tabela1, chamado countTabela1 e
outra na tabela2, chamado countTabela2 que conterão quantas linhas cada tabela possui.
Depois você fazer é criar uma tabela, chamada countTabela que possua 2 campos:
1º campo: uma chave estrangeira da tabela1, chamado FK_countTabela1;
2º campo: uma chave estrangeira da tabela2, chamado FK_countTabela2;
Só depois realizar o somatório dos 2 campos:
SELECT FK_countTabela1 + FK_countTabela2 AS Total FROM countTabela;